# codeigniter - MySQL - PHP Trying to count occurrences of different values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table
Table:

1. id   Name
2. 1    John
3. 2    James
4. 3    John
5. 4    James
6. 5    Mary

This is what I am trying to achieve.

1. Name  count
2. John  2
3. James 2
4. Mary  1

I am using this code from controller:

```
$data['total_rows'] = $this->MyModel->count_Names();

public function count_names()
{
     $name1 = $this->db->get_where('Name_table',array('name'=>'John'));
     return $name1    = $name1->num_rows();
}
```

Above code is tedious and redundant.
Are there any suggestions to make it clean.
Just one code to find out all the occurrences of the names seperately.
Thanks

Comment: `select name, count(*) from name_table group by name`

Comment: How do you write in Codeigniter way. I am kind of new to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The active record style :

```
$this->db->select('name, COUNT(*) as total');
$this->db->group_by('name');
$result = $this->db->get('Name_table');
$result_array = $result->result_array();  //Get the result as array
foreach($result_array as $name) {
    echo $name['name'].' - '.$name['total'];
}
```

Comment: Updated a bit the query, with more info for you to understand

Comment: I got this error: FUNCTION empname.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: Sorry, there was a whitespace after COUNT. Delete the whitespace between 'COUNT' and '(*)'

Comment: No problem ! Don't forget to upgrade to MAMP v3, it is a brand new version !